# Jquery how to group dictionary array at table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I work with dictionary arrays, so i have big quantity data, and i need to group it.

So i group it by hours, and in the end i recived data like this:

[image]

So problem is, i have table at which i need to store data by hours, and i have data by hours, and i need to group this data to one line.

Code:

```
var lpmsData = [
    { item: "111000355B", order: "9999999999", actual: "59", target: "504", defects: "5", efficiency: 66, pefomance: 66, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 5},
    { item: "102211549B", order: "8888888887", actual: "504", target: "366", defects: "123", efficiency: 125, pefomance: 96, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 5 },
    { item: "112255458C", order: "7777777777", actual: "777", target: "555", defects: "1", efficiency: 155, pefomance: 102, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 6  },
    { item: "111225445G", order: "6666666666", actual: "403", target: "404", defects: "1", efficiency: 34, pefomance: 78, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 7  },
    { item: "584844455A", order: "5555555555", actual: "905", target: "905", defects: "1", efficiency: 100, pefomance: 68, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 8  },
    { item: "111000354B", order: "9999999999", actual: "403", target: "404", defects: "1", efficiency: 70, pefomance: 78, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 8  },
    { item: "102253212B", order: "8888888887", actual: "504", target: "366", defects: "123", efficiency: 125, pefomance: 96, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 9  },
    { item: "112241678C", order: "7777777777", actual: "777", target: "555", defects: "1", efficiency: 50, pefomance: 102, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 10  },
    { item: "111225456G", order: "6666666666", actual: "403", target: "404", defects: "1", efficiency: 89, pefomance: 78, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 11  },
    { item: "584844000A", order: "5555555555", actual: "905", target: "905", defects: "1", efficiency: 100, pefomance: 78, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 12  }
];

var timeShedule = [
    { firstShift: ["05:45 - 07:00", "07:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00", "10:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 13:00", "13:00 - 14:00", "14:00 - 14:45",] },
    { seccondShift: ["15:00 - 16:00", "16:00 - 17:00", "17:00 - 18:00", "18:00 - 19:00", "19:00 - 20:00", "20:00 - 21:00", "21:00 - 22:00", "22:00 - 23:00", "23:00 - 00:00",] }
];

var groupedData = groupBy(lpmsData, 'timeNumber');



function buildTable() {
    $.each(groupedData, function (i, data) {
        var categoryBuild = `<tr class=${data.efficiency}>
    <td width="150">${timeShedule[0].firstShift[i]}</td>
    <td>${data.item[0].item}</td>
    <td>${data.item[0].actual}</td> 
    <td>${data.item[0].target}</td>
    <td>${data.item[0].defects}</td>
    <td>${data.item[0].efficiency} %</td>
    <td>${data.item[0].pefomance} %</td>
    <td class="oee">${data.item[0].oee}</td>
    </tr>`;

        $('.tableData').append(categoryBuild);
        console.log(data.item)
        rowColorChange(data.item[0].efficiency);
    });

}

buildTable()

function rowColorChange(data) {
    if (data <= 50) {
        $('.tableData tr:last').css("background-color", "#FF6363");
    } else if (data <= 70) {
        $('.tableData tr:last').css("background-color", "#FEF567");
    } else if (data <= 100) {
        $('.tableData tr:last').css("background-color", "#70FE67");
    } else if (data > 100) {
        $('.tableData tr:last').css("background-color", "#53B1EB");
    }
}

function sortByKey(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function (a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".footer").hide();
    sortByKey(lpmsData, "startTime");
});

function groupBy(arr, key) {
    var newArr = [],
        types = {},
        newItem, i, j, cur;
    for (i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
        cur = arr[i];
        if (!(cur[key] in types)) {
            types[cur[key]] = { date: cur[key], item: [] };
            newArr.push(types[cur[key]]);
        }
        types[cur[key]].item.push(cur);
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Item number</th>
                <th>Actual</th>
                <th>Target</th>
                <th>Defects</th>
                <th>Efficiency</th>
                <th>Performance</th>
                <th class="oee">OEE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tableData">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

So as u can see i have mok data, at which i have **timeNumber** use this timeNumber i group data at one array.

In one group i collect data for first line, but it's, separate.

So in the end i must have:

[image]

I hope i explained good.

Comment: When you talk about "collecting data" into hourly groups, do you mean that you want to calculate sums and averages? Currently you seem to consider only one item for each group.

Comment: @cars10m at tis stahe i didn't want to calculate sums and averages

Comment: OK, but where is the problem you need to have fixed? Is it that you want to have *all* items listed per group instead of just the first one?

Comment: @cars10m i want group data by hours, and now i do it, but at one line at table i need to show 1,2 or 3 values, but till now i didn't found solution

Comment: @cars10m at seccond image i show how i want to group data, for first hour i have two value, and i need to show this 2 values at one line in table

Comment: There is insufficient data: 8 `timeNumber` `Set([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])` groups yet there are 9 time slots in each array of `timeShedule`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this answer comes a little late, but maybe you are still interested. I basically rewrote all of your JavaScript parts to show that often you can do more by writing less.

The grouping stage already transforms the `lpmsData` object into an array of arrays. These arrays are then much easier to handle using `.map()` or `.reduce()` methods.

The color-changer and the sorting functions were also shortened. I commented out the sort-function as it is not really necessary for the timeNumber. However, sorting by efficiency might turn out to be of interest ...

My interpretation of "collecting" several results into one timeNumber was to put the relevant records behind a time-code `<td>` with `rowspan="n"` with `n` spanning as many rows as there are results for the given timeNumber.

I had a few doubts when it came to translating your `timeNumber` to actual times from your `timeSchedule` object which I also simplified to the array `times`. Currently a timeNumber of 5 does not seem to correspond to any given time slot.

```js
var lpmsData = [
    { item: "111000355B", order: "9999999999", actual: "59", target: "504", defects: "5", efficiency: 66, pefomance: 66, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 5},
    { item: "102211549B", order: "8888888887", actual: "504", target: "366", defects: "123", efficiency: 125, pefomance: 96, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 5 },
    { item: "112255458C", order: "7777777777", actual: "777", target: "555", defects: "1", efficiency: 155, pefomance: 102, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 6  },
    { item: "111225445G", order: "6666666666", actual: "403", target: "404", defects: "1", efficiency: 34, pefomance: 78, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 7  },
    { item: "584844455A", order: "5555555555", actual: "905", target: "905", defects: "1", efficiency: 100, pefomance: 68, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 8  },
    { item: "111000354B", order: "9999999999", actual: "403", target: "404", defects: "1", efficiency: 70, pefomance: 78, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 8  },
    { item: "102253212B", order: "8888888887", actual: "504", target: "366", defects: "123", efficiency: 125, pefomance: 96, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 9  },
    { item: "112241678C", order: "7777777777", actual: "777", target: "555", defects: "1", efficiency: 50, pefomance: 102, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 10  },
    { item: "111225456G", order: "6666666666", actual: "403", target: "404", defects: "1", efficiency: 89, pefomance: 78, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 11  },
    { item: "584844000A", order: "5555555555", actual: "905", target: "905", defects: "1", efficiency: 100, pefomance: 78, oee: "N/A", timeNumber: 12  }
];

var times = [["05:45 - 07:00", "07:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00", "10:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 13:00", "13:00 - 14:00", "14:00 - 14:45",],
["15:00 - 16:00", "16:00 - 17:00", "17:00 - 18:00", "18:00 - 19:00", "19:00 - 20:00", "20:00 - 21:00", "21:00 - 22:00", "22:00 - 23:00", "23:00 - 00:00",]
];

var getcolor= v=>'upto'+(v<=50?50:v<=70?70:v<=100?100:'anything');
var cols=['item','actual','target','defects','efficiency','pefomance','oee'],cls=[];
var grp=lpmsData // .sort((a,b)=>a.efficiency-b.efficiency)
        .reduce((coll,el)=>{if (!coll[el.timeNumber]) coll[el.timeNumber]=[];
        coll[el.timeNumber].push(cols.map(c=>el[c])); return coll},{});           
$(function (){
  $('.tableData').append(Object.keys(grp).map(tc=>
            '<tr><td class="tc" rowspan="'+grp[tc].length+'">'+tc+': '+times[0][tc-6]
           +'</td><td>'+grp[tc].map(tl=>{cls.push(tl[4]);return tl.join('</td><td>')})
           .join('</td></tr><tr><td>')
           +'</td></tr>').join("\n"));
 $('tr:gt(0)').each((i,tr)=>tr.className=getcolor(cls[i]));
});
```

```css
.upto50 {background-color:#FF6363}
.upto70 {background-color:#FEF567}
.upto100 {background-color:#70FE67}
.uptoanything {background-color:#53B1EB}
td.tc {background-color:#eee}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><thead><tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>Item number</th>
  <th>Actual</th>
  <th>Target</th>
  <th>Defects</th>
  <th>Efficiency</th>
  <th>Performance</th>
  <th class="oee">OEE</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody class="tableData">
  </tbody>
</table>
```